# How to get parameter from url split by colon (:)

Tags: php, parse-url

I have this url: "http://example.com/search/dep_city:LON/arr_city=NYC".
How can i get the values "LON" and "NYC" from this url in PHP?
This would be easy if url would be in format "dep_city=LON" by using "$_GET['dep_city']" but in this case i am confused how to do this.
Thanks in advance for your time and help.

Comment: Is your application routed? Will everything go to 1 script independent of the URL? Because normal apache will try and find a directory called dep_city:LON without some proper framework or endpoint.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes, everything will go to 1 script.

Comment: I'd use a combination of regex and $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]. Working on an example.

Comment: Thanks in advance for your time. I would very much appreciate a full code snippet, if possible.

Comment: Just added it. ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the URL from the server, explode it into parts.
Check the index of : or = for each part, parse it into an array.

```
<?php
$url = substr( $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], 1, strlen($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]));
$vars = explode("/", $url);

foreach($vars as $var){

    $indexEquals = strpos($var, "=");

    if($indexEquals === false){
        $indexColon = strpos($var, ":");
        $part1 = substr($var, 0, $indexColon);
        $part2 = substr($var, $indexColon+1, strlen($var));
    }else{
        $part1 = substr($var, 0, $indexEquals);
        $part2 = substr($var, $indexEquals+1, strlen($var));
    }

    $params[$part1] = $part2;
}

echo json_encode($params);
die();
```

Comment: Yes it gives the array. And after that i use json_decode to get the values (i hope i am doing right like this). Thanks for such prompt reply and for your time!

Comment: Sorry i left this alone for so long. But you don't have to use json_decode.
You just don't have to encode it. That was just added to be able to print it for testing.